# Is there a way of adding a java bean to a javafx scene

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I am writing a javafx application that reads a signature using the topaz signature pad, but in the demo program from the vendor they use swing and  ajava bean which can directly be added to a swing application, which is not the case with javafx, is there a way of adding the bean to a javafx scene

I have tried using `SwingNode` and adding a JPanel to it, then adding the bean to the panel but it doesn't work

the bean I am using

```
 ClassLoader cl = (com.topaz.sigplus.SigPlus.class).getClassLoader();
     sigObj = (SigPlus) Beans.instantiate(cl, "com.topaz.sigplus.SigPlus");
```

the **sigObj** from the bean is supposed to be added to the **scene**, in that it displays the signature while someone is writing, but that is not happening

Comment: “but it doesnt work” —How can you tell?  Is there an exception?

Comment: @VGR , it doesn't throw any exceptions but the signature doesn't appear on the screen when some one is signing but when using the [demo](https://gist.github.com/kamasuPaul/9d2192a2f7c899a0ddec9139df24b08e) it appears, i think it is caused by the failure for  `SwingNode` to paint heavyweight components as in the [docs] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html)

Comment: I think you’re probably right.  In which case, there isn’t much you can do, other than asking Topaz Systems to update their Java component to extend JPanel instead of Canvas.  (Using straight AWT for painting is a pretty ancient practice, and they should be embarrassed to be doing it.)